# How can I remove previous workflow runs when converting a draft PR to a ready-for-review PR in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

Converting a draft PR into a ready-for-review PR does not remove old/stale workflow runs.

I have set the following `pull_request` `types` in the workflow:

```yaml
pull_request:
types: [ 'opened', 'reopened', 'synchronize', 'ready_for_review', converted_to_draft ]
```

When I move from draft PR to `ready-for-review`, GitHub is creating new workflow runs without removing the older ones:

[image: screenshot]

How to remove the older runs?

I could not find out any ways to disable the older runs.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be performed automatically on draft PR conversion.

However, you can automate this using [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) in a separate step using its [`gh run list`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_run_list) and [`gh run delete`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_run_delete) commands after filtering for `pull_request` event and its `ready_for_review` type.

Here's an example in [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html):

```yaml
- name: Remove previous runs
  if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'ready_for_review' }}
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    BRANCH: ${{ github.ref_name }}
  shell: bash
  run: |
    for rid in $(gh run list --branch "$BRANCH" --json databaseId --jq '.[] | join("")'); do
      gh run delete "$rid"
    done
```

Also, see [Using GitHub CLI in workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/using-github-cli-in-workflows) and [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/).

---

You'll be required to configure `permissions` for the default `GITHUB_TOKEN` to make this work:

```yaml
permissions:
  actions: write
```

See [Automatic token authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication) for more details.

Comment: You can also use `gh ... --jq` instead of piping to `jq -r`. It uses the built-in [gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq).