# Github Self-hosted Runners: Remove logs

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

When using a self-hosted runner for Github actions, the log files seem to be stored in `actions-runner/_diag/`. How can I clean up these logs either at the start of a workflow run? I know we have to use the `rm` command, but it is unclear where exactly the working directory of self-hosted runners start from.

Comment: Can you simply not delete the existing workflow run(s) at the start of a workflow and the respective logs should be deleted automatically?

Comment: Here's a relevant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76387408/7670262) and [here](https://github.com/iamazeem/substitute-action/blob/b3bad24a0744ebd2dd8bf4b02522d246bb6a4815/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L41-L48) is another example where only the latest workflow run is kept.